# Convention for adding data to a clickable element

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

This question is perhaps too philosophical for SO but I wanted to give it a try.

We are using a tool called Google-Tag-Manager to track website events. GTM listens for clicks and you can filter based on e.g. element class or id.

Consider this scenario. We have several pdfs on  particular page and wnat to know how popular they are. The pdfs can either be downloaded or viewed online. The pdfs each have a name. So I need to get the following data:

- whether downloaded pdf or viewed online
- the name of the pdf

For name we can presumably use name or title attribute. But whether viewed online or downloaded is more custom.

I am currently going to ask our developers to edit the html in such a way that I can configure GTM to listen for these clicks and pass the data back into our web reporting tool.

I can tell them to add a class to all of them e.g. class='pdf_clicks". What would a conventional means of adding the other two data points? A custom attribute? I know I can use title for name. What about whehter or not was viewed online or downloaded? Is there a generic meta data type attribute for this?

Comment: Don't you have to download a PDF to view it online?

Comment: This will only work if you have separate buttons for  "Read online" and "Download" (in which case different class attributes will do fine). You cannot track the PDF itself (no tracking code in a binary file), you can only track clicks. And like @EricUldall I think the difference between "downloaded" and "viewed online" is somewhat artifical.